# Malformed HTTP Requests

Tags: http, request

I am seeing a significant amount of HTTP requests to multiple web services that I operate which look like this:

```
[[#22]][[#3]][[#1]][[#1]] [[#1]][[#0]][[#1]][[#28]][[#3]][[#3]]MÚ [[#7]]eÀ…Æ¦­á"¢ÛË…'Ð8zÃE¹ÔH“¶·[[#22]]~  
À[[#20]][[#0]]9À À[[#19]][[#0]]3[[#0]][[#0]][[#0]]=[[#0]]<[[#0]]5[[#0]]/[[#0]]ÿ[[#1]][[#0]][[#0]][[#0]][[#11]][[#0]][[#4]][[#3]][[#0]][[#1]][[#2]][[#0]]:
[[#0]][[#12]][[#0]]:
[[#0]][[#29]][[#0]][[#23]][[#0]][[#30]][[#0]][[#25]][[#0]][[#24]][[#0]]#[[#0]][[#0]][[#0]][[#22]][[#0]][[#0]][[#0]][[#23]][[#0]][[#0]][[#0]] [[#0]]0[[#0]].[[#4]][[#3]][[#5]][[#3]][[#6]][[#3]][[#8]][[#7]][[#8]][[#8]][[#8]] [[#8]]:
[[#8]][[#11]][[#8]][[#4]][[#8]][[#5]][[#8]][[#6]][[#4]][[#1]][[#5]][[#1]][[#6]][[#1]][[#3]][[#3]][[#2]][[#3]][[#3]][[#1]][[#2]][[#1]][[#3]][[#2]][[#2]][[#2]][[#4]][[#2]][[#5]][[#2]][[#6]][[#2]][[#0]]+[[#0]] [[#8]][[#3]][[#4]][[#3]][[#3]][[#3]][[#2]][[#3]][[#1]][[#0]]-[[#0]][[#2]][[#1]][[#1]][[#0]]3[[#0]]&[[#0]]$[[#0]][[#29]][[#0]] U¿[[#19]]|}¯ $Â[[#1]]`¤^;d{²À[[#11]]&[[#20]]ó1Z:
```

It does seem to be an abnormal and potentially malicious request but I am having a hard time decoding it to understand its intent or how it may be harmful. Is there any specific context on why are these requests so heavily used, what are they trying to achieve and how to properly decode their intent?

Comment: What kind of webserver? Where do you see those requests? What have you tried already?

Comment: Tools like Burp Suite, OWASP ZAP, and YARA can be used to analyze and decode payloads, including those that use various encoding and obfuscation techniques.

Comment: I thought it looked like https traffic hitting a http server - but you didn't tell us how this information was captured / encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing malformed HTTP requests with Burp Suite can be quite challenging due to the variability of malformed requests. Here's a simplified Python script that demonstrates how to analyze malformed HTTP requests using Burp Suite:

```python
from burp import IBurpExtender
from burp import ITab
from burp import IHttpListener
from burp import IHttpRequestResponse
from burp import IRequestInfo

# Import the required Burp API classes

class BurpExtender(IBurpExtender, ITab, IHttpListener):
    def registerExtenderCallbacks(self, callbacks):
        self._callbacks = callbacks
        self._helpers = callbacks.getHelpers()

        # Set the extension name and add the tab to Burp Suite
        callbacks.setExtensionName("Malformed Request Analyzer")
        callbacks.addSuiteTab(self)

        # Register HTTP listener to capture requests and responses
        callbacks.registerHttpListener(self)

    def getTabCaption(self):
        return "Malformed Request Analyzer"

    def getUiComponent(self):
        return None

    def processHttpMessage(self, toolFlag, messageIsRequest, messageInfo):
        if messageIsRequest:
            # Process request
            request = messageInfo.getRequest()
            analyzed_payload = self.analyze_request(request)
            if analyzed_payload:
                self.alert_on_malformed_request(analyzed_payload)

    def analyze_request(self, request):
        try:
            # Parse the request
            request_info = self._helpers.analyzeRequest(request)
            
            # Implement your analysis logic here
            # Check for malformed request patterns or any other issues
            
            # Example: Check if the request contains an excessively long header
            for header in request_info.getHeaders():
                if len(header) > 1000:
                    return "Malformed Request: Excessive Header Length"
            
            # Return the analyzed payload or None if no issues are found
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            return "Error analyzing request: " + str(e)

    def alert_on_malformed_request(self, payload):
        # Implement how you want to alert on malformed requests
        # This could be logging, sending alerts, or any other action

# Instantiate the BurpExtender class
burp_extender = BurpExtender()
```

In this script:

1. We implement an extension for Burp Suite that acts as a "Malformed Request Analyzer" and registers an HTTP listener to capture HTTP requests.
2. In the `processHttpMessage` method, we process HTTP requests and call the `analyze_request` method to perform custom analysis on the request content. You should implement your analysis logic in this method.
3. If a malformed request is detected (based on your analysis), the `alert_on_malformed_request` method can be used to define how you want to alert or handle the malformed request.

Please note that this script provides a basic framework for analyzing malformed requests. You'll need to extend and customize the analysis logic to suit your specific requirements and scenarios. Additionally, you'll need to install and configure this Burp Suite extension within the Burp Suite application itself.